# react redux toolkit unable to write logic for addtoprogress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

im finding hard time in getting handson redux toolkit
here im trying to move a task from todo to inprogress
addtodo is working fine but addprogress is not working
could anyone help me please? Im a newbie

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import counterReducer from "./features/counter/counterSlice";
import todoReducer from "./features/todo/todosSlice";
import progressReducer from './features/inProgress/inProgressSlice'
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    // counter: counterReducer,
    todos: todoReducer,
    progress :progressReducer
  },
});

export default store;
```

Button in todo.js

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
       dispatch(addProgress(todo.id))
      }}
     >
```

Here in todo.js i have id whch im passing as a payload

progress.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const InProgress = () => {
  const progress = useSelector((state) => state.progress);
  if (!progress) {
    console.log("Loading");
  }
console.log(progress.length);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>In Progress</h2>
        <ul>
          {progress.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InProgress;
```

progressslice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const progressSlice = createSlice({
  name: "progress",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addProgress: (state, action) => {
      const todoIndex = state.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === action.payload);
      console.log(todoIndex);
      if (todoIndex !== -1) {
        const todo = state[todoIndex];
        const newState = [
          ...state.slice(0, todoIndex),
          ...state.slice(todoIndex + 1),
          todo,
        ];
        console.log("Current State: ", state);
        console.log("New State: ", newState);
        return newState;
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { addProgress } = progressSlice.actions;
export default progressSlice.reducer;
```

Here if the id matches with the id of state i need to add it im the progress state along with the previous ones which im unable to implement

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todos",
  initialState: [
  ],
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      state.push({
        id:111,
        text: action.payload,
      });
    },
    toggleTodo: (state, action) => {
      const todo = state.find((todo) => todo.id === action.payload);
      if (todo) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed;
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { addTodo, toggleTodo } = todosSlice.actions;
export default todosSlice.reducer;
```

todoslice.js is working fine

[image]

Comment: I would combine your two slices into one.  With the way that you have it now, your state.findIndex can only find todos which are already in the progress array.  You won’t be able to add another todo there.